# Base 64 decode from raw binary

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to decode base64 from raw binary:

As input, I have 4 6-bit values

010000 001010 000000 011001

which I convert to decimal, giving

16 10 0 25

and finally decode using the base 64 table, giving

Q K A Z

This is verified to be the correct result.

I would like to use Python's base64 module to automate this, but using

```
import base64
base64.b64decode( bytearray([16,10,0,25]) )
```

returns an empty string.

What is the proper way to use this library with the given inputs?

Answer (score 1):

`[16, 10, 0, 25]` isn't a base64 string, really; I don't think `base64` has any functions for converting numeric representations of the base64 alphabet to their alphabetic representations. It's not difficult to roll your own, though:

```
def to_characters(numeric_arr):
    target = b'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' + b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' + b'0123456789' + b'+/'
    return bytes(target[n] for n in numeric_arr)
```

Then:

```
>>> to_characters(bytearray([16, 10, 0, 25]))
b'QKAZ'
>>> to_characters([16, 10, 0, 25]) # <- or just this
b'QKAZ'
```

You can now pass this bytes object to `base64.b64decode`:

```
>>> base64.b64decode(b'QKAZ')
b'@\xa0\x19'
```

(Note that you had a syntax issue in your example use of `bytearray` - don't do `bytearray[...]`; do `bytearray([...])`. Python doesn't use C-like `int array[size]` syntax.)

Comment: Solution was to create my own base64 decoder table as shown above. Then I just loop over the raw bytes, look up in the table, and append the result to the decoded string. There is no need for the base64 module.